# Prevent disconnection of Bluetooth LE Service

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am making an app using Bluetooth LE Service. What I noticed is the device gets disconnected automatically after some time after app goes to background. Can someone explain reason for this?

I am getting following error.

`02-12 16:48:27.497  11695-11695/main.nesttech.com.nesttechble E/ActivityThread﹕ Activity main.nesttech.com.nesttechble.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection main.nesttech.com.nesttechble.MainActivity$1@428fc528 that was originally bound here
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity main.nesttech.com.nesttechble.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection main.nesttech.com.nesttechble.MainActivity$1@428fc528 that was originally bound here
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:979)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:873)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1818)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1806)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:503)
            at main.nesttech.com.nesttechble.MainActivity.connectDevice(MainActivity.java:429)
            at main.nesttech.com.nesttechble.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:93)
            at main.nesttech.com.nesttechble.MainActivity$4$1.run(MainActivity.java:399)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5414)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log you posted are just losing the `ServiceConnection`, which is used to connect your `Activity` to your `Service` object by `bindService`.
Beware it's **Android** `Service` object but not BLE service implemented in the peripheral.

This has nothing to do with BLE connection, probably your background `Activity` just get killed by the system to free memory, and you did not do `unbindService` in suitable lifecycle callback before the activity dies.

Comment: Thanks @reTs for the answer... We ourselves eventually found out that the background `Activity` was getting killed to free memory and taken care of it in `onDestroy` mathod... Your answer matches this so i am marking it as answer for others...